# C code optimization

Tags: c, optimization

I'm trying to optimize some C code, and it's my first time.
As a first step i dumped my executable file in order to see the assembler code.
For example for this function:

```
void init_twiddle(int N)
{
  int i=0;
  for(i=0; i<ELEMENTS_HALF; i++)
  {    
     twiddle_table[i].re = (float)   cos((float)i * 2.0 * PI / (float)N);
     twiddle_table[i].im = (float) - sin((float)i * 2.0 * PI / (float)N);
  }
}
```

wouldn't be better if i do this instead:

```
    void init_twiddle(int N)
{
  int i=0;
  float puls = 2.0 * PI / (float)N;
  for(i=0; i<ELEMENTS_HALF; i++)
  {    
     twiddle_table[i].re = (float)   cos((float)i * puls);
     twiddle_table[i].im = (float) - sin((float)i * puls);
  }
```

in order to avoid mult and div operation of being repeated thousands of times?
    }

Comment: Chances are, it would. You wouldn't expect the compiler to figure it out on its own, do you?

Comment: This a simple matter of bench marking the application. My initial thoughts would be that it would be negligible except when N is substantial. Or as Amin Negm-Awad has pointed out in the answer, it would be irrelevant, as the compiler might have done it for you, so long as you have enabled the optimization flags.

Comment: What the assembly code has to do with this?

Comment: The `(float)` casts are unnecessary. Removing them will have no effect on the generated code. However, declaring `puls` as a `float` will definitely reduce the accuracy of your results.

Comment: You can do much more here. For example calculate `i*puls` just once per loop. Use a `sincos` function calculating sine and cosine in the same shot (if available). Replace sine/cosine calculation with a lookup table and so on. But what is the question?

Comment: Optimization is a rather exact action, dealing with measurement of time and CPU resources consumed and rewriting code with the aim of economizing them. Another point is _good programing practice_, which would avoid casts and multiplication of constants inside loops. Also, unless dealing with specific real-time code (such as audio) using native format `float`, use `double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, your *first step* was already kindof wrong.

Don't blindly walk through your code optimizing arbitrary loops which might or (more probably) might not affect performance (maybe because that code is so rarely called that it doesn't really use any run-time).

Optimizing means: You need to find out first *where is the time spent in my program*? Use timing measurements to narrow down where your program spends most of its time (you can use homegrown logging using us timers or a profiling application for that). Without at least some figures you wouldn't even see where the compiler has already helped you and maybe has already maxed out all possibilities, even if your code looks like it has some potential left for being faster (modern compilers are really very good at that).

Only if you know the hot spots in your application you should start optimizing those.

Comment: @ tofro your answer look more logical to me.
and this is what i will do

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that it is a floating point expression and floating point operations are not commutative. So the optimization is invalid in general for any compiler that follows IEEE 754. So either you have to do this optimization manually, or you have to tell the compiler to treat floating point as commutative for optimization purposes (in gcc and clang you use `-ffast-math` to do this). This will introduce slight changes in the resulting values.

For comparison of the assembly:

- [Without -ffast-math](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g492,options:'-O3',source:'%23include+%3Cmath.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+ELEMENTS_HALF+2048%0Astruct+%7B%0A+++float+re%3B%0A+++float+im%3B%0A%7D+twiddle_table%5BELEMENTS_HALF%5D%3B%0A%0Avoid+init_twiddle(int+N)%0A%7B%0A++int+i%3D0%3B%0A++for(i%3D0%3B+i%3CELEMENTS_HALF%3B+i%2B%2B)%0A++%7B++++%0A+++++twiddle_table%5Bi%5D.re+%3D+(float)+++cos((float)i+*+2.0+*+M_PI+/+(float)N)%3B%0A+++++twiddle_table%5Bi%5D.im+%3D+(float)+-+sin((float)i+*+2.0+*+M_PI+/+(float)N)%3B%0A++%7D%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)
- [With -ffast-math](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g492,options:'-O3+-ffast-math',source:'%23include+%3Cmath.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+ELEMENTS_HALF+2048%0Astruct+%7B%0A+++float+re%3B%0A+++float+im%3B%0A%7D+twiddle_table%5BELEMENTS_HALF%5D%3B%0A%0Avoid+init_twiddle(int+N)%0A%7B%0A++int+i%3D0%3B%0A++for(i%3D0%3B+i%3CELEMENTS_HALF%3B+i%2B%2B)%0A++%7B++++%0A+++++twiddle_table%5Bi%5D.re+%3D+(float)+++cos((float)i+*+2.0+*+M_PI+/+(float)N)%3B%0A+++++twiddle_table%5Bi%5D.im+%3D+(float)+-+sin((float)i+*+2.0+*+M_PI+/+(float)N)%3B%0A++%7D%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this much faster, indeed you need only 1 sine and 1 cosine (which are disastrously slow). What you're actually doing is calculating the coordinates of a little vector that you spin around the origin, the alternative way to do it is by actually spinning that vector around the origin, one step at the time. The rotation matrix for a single step is what costs the single sine and cosine.

Of course this may be a bit less accurate, but no significant trouble should build up if you make a a reasonable number of steps.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine because you could see what the user was trying to do. No need to call built-in functions more than once.

Comment: Well, there are numerous ways to optimize it, if the question is about it. Like calculating a single quadrant only while using the identities like `sin(pi/2+x)=cos(x)` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

*The root of all evil is premature optimization*
– Donald Knuth

You should optimize, if you have a problem with execution duration. There are tools that record the duration of every single statement or at least function call.

I think that most compilers detect such constant expressions in a loop and there is nothing to optimize, because it is already optimized.

Comment: The example above *is not* a pre-mature optimization.

Comment: You cannot say that, because you do not know, whether it is necessary.

Comment: And you can not say that it is not, @AminNegm-Awad, because you do not know what the OP has measured.

Comment: *This* is correct. @AShelly And that is the reason, why my answer do not stop with this part. I did *not* say, that it is premature optimization. (However, I said that it is likely, because the compiler detects invariants.) What Eugen said, was definitely wrong. This is the original quotation: *Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, …*

Comment: Taking a common factor out of the brackets is a premature optimization?? It is a common sense.

Comment: The optimization is invalid given the guarantees major compilers make about floating point, so the compiler will probably not optimize it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Whether something is a premature optimization does not depend on what you are doing. It is premature, if you do it before measuring whether it is necessary.

Comment: @user1937198 Yes, this is a good point as I commented in your answer.

Comment: When the OP writes "*As a first step i dumped my executable file in order to see the assembler code.*" - I would consider that a definitive sign of pre-mature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `double`, not `float`. In C, library routines are all in `double`, so you're just doing a lot of converting.

Second, calculate the angle once and put it in a variable, not twice.
Maybe the compiler recognizes that it can do this for you, but I prefer not to tempt the compiler not to.

Third, is there a `sincos` function? The sine and cosine functions are closely related, so one can be calculated at the same time as the other.

Fourth, when thinking about performance, switch your brain to thinking in *percent of total time*, not doing something "thousands of times". That way, you will concentrate on what has the greatest overall benefit, not things that might well be irrelevant.

Comment: If you use the right flags, the compiler can optimise this, including using sincos, and vectorizing.

Comment: @user1937198: Maybe so, and maybe not. Why tempt fate?

Comment: @user1937198 Let the compiler do the non-obvious stuff. Do the obvious yourself.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Because how can you write vectorized code in standard C?

Comment: @user1937198: Hey, if the compiler wants to vectorize, let 'er rip. My preference is to ease the burden on the optimizer if it's practically free.

Answer (score -1):

This probably won't change your code performance, since this a standard loop invariants optimization that is performed by any standard compiler (assuming optimizations aren't turned off)..